# Prospects of Australian Ph.D. holder in CSE

Tags: phd, job, industry, australia

please forgive my ignorance as I am from a third world country where people hardly pursue a Ph.D, so I am very unknowledgeable regarding this.

I have recently been accepted for a fully funded Ph.D in CS at a top 5 university in Australia. My research focus is mainly on Computer Vision and Deep Learning. What are the prospects of a Ph.D holder in Australia in industries? I am not interested in academia/teaching and I find myself mostly interested in R&D. For jobs in Europe or North America, will an Australian Ph.D hold as much value as a similarly ranked US one?

Comment: Given that most of the research in the areas you mention are in academia you have a very narrow path worldwide. Most "research" in industry is product focused rather than knowledge focused. It won't be the "ranking" of your degree that matters but the number of available positions thereafter. But your Australian degree should be at least as good as any other.

Comment: @Buffy  It's a bit odd to claim that computer vision and deep learning are "in academia" and a "narrow path."  There are quite a few self-driving car projects in industry.

Comment: To sort-of respond to the question:  your visa status is going to matter more than which country your PhD came from.   Also, if you want to develop products industry, you do not need a PhD.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, who collectively employ a vast number of researchers with doctorates? I'd guess not.

Comment: @Buffy It took me just a couple of seconds to google that: https://www.cnbc.com/2017/07/28/this-tech-company-has-the-most-highly-educated-employees.html "16 percent of positions at Google require a doctorate degree."  Also, I just said the asker didn't need a PhD.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, unfortunately jobs in technology are very scarce in my country, and product development is virtually non existent. My bachelor's degree is from a 1000+ ranked university nobody in the world will recognize. As far as I know, it is very difficult to obtain funding for Masters degrees. So a Ph.D is my best option at growing my career. Plus I really enjoy research.

Comment: It seems your problem is your location, not your degree.  Also, starting a business is a possibility.  It takes less time than a PhD.

Comment: Usually a masters is required before starting a PhD in Australia.  Your situation sounds odd.

Comment: I don't think anyone would disparage an Australian degree per se, especially since you're at one of the best Australian institutes. The bigger problem is that employers would have to sponsor you for a visa (I speak from a US perspective here), which will put you at a huge disadvantage compared to local candidates. Anyway: we do take questions about industry R&D here, but you might also try asking at [workplace.SE].

Answer (score 1):

The top five Australian universities are highly ranked worldwide and have strong programs in computer science and related fields.  A PhD from any one of these universities would be sufficient to give you a strong grounding for a job in industry.  (Indeed, this is more that what you would need to obtain a job in computing work in industry.)

It is likely that you will need to obtain an appropriate working visa or residency in order to secure an industry position after your degree.  This is also something that is feasible if you undertake a PhD position.  While working as an academic at an Australian university, I supervised a student who migrated here from Nigeria during his PhD.  By the time he successfully completed his program he had earned permanent residency and he has since secured an academic position here.